# Setting a specific class to "display:none" depending on screen width

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a website recently that needs to have a header with the 4 menu items, and then the menu as the final header that expands for the 4 menu items. I'm attempting to make it so that when you have a device that won't fit the 4 menu items, it won't show them and will only show the menu.

HTML:

```
<!-- Header -->
            <header id="header">
                <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><span>Placeholder</span></a></div>
                <a href="index.html#about" class="scrolly optional">About</a>
                <a href="#types" class="scrolly optional">Clients</a>
                <a href="team.html" class="optional">Team</a>
                <a href="contact.html" class="optional">Contact</a>
                <a href="#menu">Menu</a>
            </header>

        <!-- Nav -->
            <nav id="menu">
                <ul class="links">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#types">Clients</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 730px) {
    a.optional {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have tried using classes to select the specific links, but it doesn't work as intended. Thanks in advance for the help!
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4c3cgeqx/

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: What doesn't work exactly ? I just pasted your code in a fiddle and looks like it does what you are asking for: https://jsfiddle.net/p9j0r7wv/

Comment: It looks to me like this should work, but I take it that some or all still appear on small screens? My guess would be a conflicting style rule or an `!important` in play. Use your browser's developer inspector to see exactly what rule is applying the `display` state and report back. You could always use your own `!important`, but it's better to figure out another solution.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle with the full css. I still haven't managed to figure out what is conflicting. Link: https://jsfiddle.net/4c3cgeqx/